# Hanging Ceiling Joists UNDER New Attic Header?

Tags: joists

I’m opening a load bearing wall between the kitchen and living room. I’ve overcome the offset basement girder with two new posts under the joists that will carry the new header load down from the attic. Header is sized at (2)2x10 and will rest at roughly an 8’ span. The joists that cross the load bearing wall and overlap are not the same size. 2x6 over kitchen and 2x8 over living room. Here is my plan and I’d love input on under/over built. I’d much rather error on the side of over. — Explaining the drawing below I plan to notch the 2x8 down to 2x6 height so the buried header can “rest” on both joists during the build even though eventually the load will be carried at the ends. This will allow for the use of face mount joist hangers to be attached to the joists and beam. Since they are hanging below I plan to used very deep hangers to grab the joists and still allow a minimum of 5” of attachment to the header. The kitchen side is going to have to be a double hanger since both joists cross under the header on that side, planning a MiTek HU214-2 or similar. The living room side can be a single since the 2x8 only extends that way, planning a MiTek HD216 or similar. — This is the best and strongest way I’ve come up with. Thank you. [image][image]

Comment: Your intent is to have the header sitting on top of the joists? What's going to hold the joists up at the point of overlap between 2x6 & 2x8 where you've got the additional load of a header sitting on top of a joint? You've only got ~4" of overlap between the 2x6 & 2x8 - that doesn't seem to me to be very much for attaching the two together.

Comment: The 2x8 (living room side) will be hung from the header - right side of drawing. The 2x6 doubled with 2x8 tail (kitchen side) will be hung from the header - left side of the drawing. The header really isn’t imposing any weight on the joists at this point. The header is supported on the ends with proper studs running from under the header down to a floor joist through to new basement posts under the floor joists. The header will HANG the joists instead of having them rest on it. This way there is no bump out in the ceiling between rooms.

Comment: You might consider shortening the studs and having the bottom of the header flush with the ceiling, then using joist hanger in the more traditional sense where the bottoms (or tops, depending) will be flush, then but the 2x6s & 2x8 up to the bottom of the header. I'm not sure that joist hangers are designed to literally _hang_ a joist below a header like that. It may work fine, but it's just not something I've seen before. Not a structural engineer, or even a builder, so not an answer, just a strong concern.

Comment: Thank you @FreeMan. I have considered doing that as well. My thought is not having to remove the wall underneath until the header is secured (although still building temp walls on each side).